# How to compute the divergence in polar coordinates from the Voss-Weyl formula?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, tensors, vector-fields

The [Voss-Weyl formula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD2AiFk651E) reads
$$\nabla_\mu V^\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt g}\partial_\mu(\sqrt g V^\mu),$$
where $g=\mathrm{det}( g_{\mu\nu})$. In polar plane coordinates the only non-vanishing components of the metric tensor are $g_{rr}=1$ and $g_{\theta\theta}=r^2$, so $g=r$. Then the divergence in this coordinate system as given by the above expression is
$$\nabla_\mu V^\mu=\frac{1}{r}\partial_r(rV^r)+\partial_\theta V^\theta.$$

But the divergence formula in polar coordinates is the [well known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Cylindrical_coordinates)
$$\nabla_\mu V^\mu=\frac{1}{r}\partial_r(rV_r)+\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta V_\theta.$$
What am I missing in the previous calculation?

Comment: In the first formula, $V^\theta$ is the coordinate wrt the vector $\partial_\theta$, which has length $r$. In the second formula, $V_\theta$ is the coordinate wrt the vector $e_\theta$ that has unit length; so $V_\theta = r V^\theta$. ...I think.

Comment: @user66081 How do I see that the vector $\partial_\theta$ has length $r$?

Comment: @user362271 :That's because $g_{\theta\theta}  =r^2$.

Comment: Writing a vector $d\vec r$ in terms of the unit vectors $\hat e_i$ we have $d\vec r=dr\hat e_r+rd\theta\hat e_\theta$. Is it that we just define new basis vectors $\vec e_i\equiv \partial_i$ in such a way that $d\vec r=dr\vec e_r+d\theta\vec e_\theta=dr\partial_r+d\theta\partial_\theta$? Then $\partial_\theta=r\hat e_\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

The polar coordinates orthonormal basis is $\partial_\mu = \{\partial_r, \frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta\}$, which you can see by transforming from the cartesian coordinate system. Hence the $\frac{1}{r}$ in the final expression.